# Use a post method to screen is displayed

Tags: android

I would like to know how to use a method after I visualize my activity, because I need to see activity before then apply the method.

Ever tried putting the method in onResume () however it has not yet appeared on the screen then do not work for my case.

Comment: You need to clarify what you need here with and example.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your method inside `doInbackground()` of an `Asynctask` and then update the UI of your activity in `onPostexecute()`.